# update\replace df [cols] by df [cols]

Tags: python, pandas, replace, updates

i have two df with the same index, and i like to update\replace list of cols only when name=="A".

so where i got name=="A" i want it to replace
lits of cols ->cols=[col1,col2,col3,col4]

so i have this df

```
first_data={"col1":[2,3,4,5,7],
"col2":[4,2,4,6,4],
"col3":[7,6,9,11,2],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(first_data)
df1
```

and the sec df

```
sec_df={"col1":[55,0,57,1,3],
"col2":[55,0,4,4,53],
"col3":[55,33,9,0,2],
"col4":[55,0,22,4,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"hight":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sec_df)
df2
```

i like to do somting like this
df1.loc[df1["name"]=="A"][cols]=df2.loc[df2["name"]=="A"][cols]

so i want to get this

```
data={"col1":[55,0,4,1,7],
"col2":[55,0,4,4,4],
"col3":[55,33,9,0,2],
"col4":[55,0,22,4,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can `update`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index("name", append=True)

df1.update(df2[df2["name"].eq("A")].set_index("name", append=True).filter(like="col"))
```

If you don't need to care about the column `name` and solely need to update base on index, you can simply do:

```
df1.update(df2[df2["name"].eq("A")].filter(like="col"))

  name  col1  col2  col3  col4  n_roll
0    A  55.0  55.0  55.0  55.0       8
1    A   0.0   0.0  33.0   0.0       2
2    V   4.0   4.0   9.0  22.0       1
3    A   1.0   4.0   0.0   4.0       3
4    B   7.0   4.0   2.0   5.0       9
```

Comment: I have to use a list of columns because in real data the names are different and it is not possible to filter by the word "COL"

maybe something like:

df1.update(df2[df2["name"].eq("A")].set_index("name", append=True)[cols]


when cols=["col1","col2",col3,"col4"]